# Tensorflow: Diagonal of matrix of matrices / Diagonal of 4D tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Given a 4D tensor `x` of shape `(batch_size, batch_size, seq_len, feature_dim)`, I want to be able to retrieve the matrices along the diagonal entries, i.e. I need a way to fetch all `x[diag_entry, diag_entry, :, :]` slices for the values `range(batch_size)` producing a tensor of shape `(batch_size, seq_len, feature_dim)`. However, I cannot explicitly loop over `range(batch_size)` as `batch_size` may vary since I work in Keras. Does Tensorflow have functionality supporting such an operation?